# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Step1Item:

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I get the error above as I am trying to use the v-for directive on a component in a component.

This is working and iterating through some data stored in participants

```
<template>
    <div
        v-for="(participant, index) in participants"
        v-bind:key="index"
        >
        hello world
    </div>
</template>
```

But changing to this gives me the above error.

```
<template>
    <Step1Item
        v-for="(participant, index) in participants"
        v-bind:key="index"
        >
        hello world
    </Step1Item>
</template>

<script>
    import Step1Item from "./Step1Item.vue";

    export default {
        name: "Step1",
        components: Step1Item,
    [...] 
</script>
```

The component is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Step1Item",
    props: {
        name: String,
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is Step1Item in the same folder as Step1?

Comment: Yes, for now it is.

Comment: You can also check this out, worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024797/vue-3-failed-to-resolve-component-with-global-components

Comment: Check this out, it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024797/vue-3-failed-to-resolve-component-with-global-components

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're writing the `components` option incorrectly, it should be :

```
 components: {Step1Item},
```

`components` option has value as object of `componentName:component` pairs but you could write it with shorthand syntax `components: {component1,component2,...},`

Comment: Thank you so much. I just wasted over 2 hours because I  added components as an array instead of an object.