# How to solve Vue-Formulate Failed to resolve component error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am a bit new to Vue and it keeps getting harder for me to crack. I'm using Vue 3 I want to use Vue-Formulate to create a registration form on my vue app. Here's how far I've come following Vue-Formulate official documentation:

```
// main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate'

createApp(App).use(VueFormulate).mount('#app')
```

Then on Register.vue:

```
<template>
  <formulate-form v-model="formValues" @submit="registerUser">
     <formulate-input name="first_name" label="First Name" placeholder="First Name" type="text"></formulate-input>
  </formulate>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'RegisterLogin',
    methods: {
        registerUser () {
            // call back here
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But I get *[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: formulate-form* and *[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: formulate-input* error from the console and the form refuses to render. I can't really tell why. Answers from here: [[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Step1Item:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836347/vue-warn-failed-to-resolve-component-step1item) are not helping as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I had to create my own form components as I could not resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

In Register.vue import all the components that you are using:

```
import { FormulateForm, FormulateInput } from '@braid/vue-formulate';
```

And then in the export method try adding components object and list the names of all the components that you are using, like this:

```
export default {
   components: {
     FormulateForm,
     FormulateInput,
     another-component-here
   },
   * the rest of the code here *
}
```