# Vue 3 - "Failed to resolve component" with global components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli, vuejs3

My Vue components work fine when declared in the top level HTML file, like this

```html
<body>
  <div class='app' id='app'>        
    <header-bar id='headerBar'></header-bar>        
    <journal-page></journal-page>
  </div>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

but using a `<journal-card>` component inside the `<journal-page>` component gives me the error:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: journal-card at `<JournalPage>`.

How do I fix this please?

Here's my top level code that loads the Vue components, `app.js`:

```js
import * as _vue from 'vue';
import _headerBar from './widgets/headerBar.vue';
import _journalCard from './widgets/journalCard.vue';
import _journalPage from './widgets/journalPage.vue';
import _store from './data/store.js';

const app = _vue.createApp
({
    components: 
    {
        'headerBar': _headerBar,
        'journalCard': _journalCard,
        'journalPage': _journalPage     
    },
    data : _store,
    methods: {}
});
const mountedApp = app.mount('#app');
```

and here's my `journal-page.vue` container

```html
<template>  
  <ul>
    <journal-card v-for="item in journal" :key="item.id" :entry=item></journal-card>
  </ul>
</template>

<script lang="js">
import _store from '../data/store.js';
export default {
  'data': _store
};
</script>
```

and `journal-card.vue` component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    hi imma journal entry
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="js">
export default {
  'data': null,
  'props': [ 'entry' ]
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Registering components in the root component's `components` option doesn't make them global.  Doing that just makes them available to the root component itself, not its children.

To register components globally, use `app.component` in your top-level code:

*main.js*

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import MyGlobalComponent from './components/MyGlobalComponent.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('MyGlobalComponent', MyGlobalComponent); ✅
const mountedApp = app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: The key part is sequence I was adding component after mounting app. above example is perfect fix for it.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was declaring components in array:

```
components: [ActiveUser, UserData]
```

which should have been in an object:

```
components: {ActiveUser, UserData}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario issue was different. I was trying to render a similar multi word Vue component in a laravel blade file.

If you're referring a Vue component in a non .Vue file (like HTML / Laravel Blade etc), you should use kebab-cased format to refer the component name. Like `my-global-component`

Vue documentation - https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats

Answer (score 1):

Also as a side note since this page shows up when looking in search engines for some problems with "Vue 3 Failed to resolve component", there are a few things that were deprecated with Vue 3 / Quasar 2:

eg. q-side-link
that silently disappeared ([previous doc here](https://v0-14.quasar-framework.org/components/layout-side-links.html))

as per this [comment](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-framework.org/blob/dev/source/guide/quasar-upgrade-guide.md):

> QSideLink -- no longer required! Simply use a QItem or whatever
> component you want and bind an @click="$router.push(...)" to it.

Sorry if it's not exactly on topic but it will bite some other people, so I prefer to help one person with this comment ;-)

Answer (score -1):

make sure the mounting code comes at last so

```
app.mount('#app')    
app.component('list-view', ListView2)
```

is wrong and it will not work but

```
app.component('list-view', ListView2)
app.mount('#app')
```

is correct.